# Python weka wrapper attribute selection

Tags: python, wrapper, weka

Question: I am using python weka wrapper for my attribute selection process but I am able to run this only for the last or the first attribute. Any ideas on how to run for any attribute?

Code:

```
# load a dataset
test_file = helper.get_data_dir() + os.sep + "test.arff"
helper.print_info("Loading dataset: " + test_file)
loader = Loader("weka.core.converters.ArffLoader")
test_data = loader.load_file(test_file)
test_data.class_is_last()

# perform attribute selection
helper.print_title("Attribute selection")
search = ASSearch(classname="weka.attributeSelection.BestFirst", options=["-D", "1", "-N", "5"])
evaluation = ASEvaluation(classname="weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval", options=["-P", "1", "-E", "1"])
attsel = AttributeSelection()
attsel.search(search)
attsel.evaluator(evaluation)
attsel.select_attributes(test_data)
print("# attributes: " + str(attsel.number_attributes_selected))
print("attributes: " + str(attsel.selected_attributes))
print("result string:\n" + attsel.results_string)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: i am not getting any error. Its just that i am only able to run the attribute selection process  for my last and first attribute. is there any way to specify the class for which i want to run the attribute selection for?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the class index of your dataset using the `class_index` property of the `Instances` object (0-based attribute index). For instance, setting the third attribute as class attribute:

```
test_data.class_index = 2
```